# Getting rid of Scientific Notation C++

Tags: c++, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I'm making a calculator in command prompt, and lately I have been trying out different algorithms for square root. The one that I am using returns in a double, which I want, but brings a problem. When I print the double into command prompt, if it is more than 6 digits, it uses scientific notation. I would like to view the number normally, since It really isn't that big. Is there any way to print it in standard form?

Comment: This is up to the method used to convert to string and/or print. What are you using? `std::cout`?

Comment: what is "normally" / "standard form" ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the std::fixed stream manipulator (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Use [stream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/), in your case:

```
std::cout.fixed;
std::cout << number_value;
```